# How to store list of matches in an array in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have my pattern like this

```
[^h1]
```

And my text is

```
ash1a
```

How can I retrieve all the matches and store them in an array?

```
[0] = a
[1] = s
[2] = a
```

In a site called regexr.com, it lists all the characters on the LIST tab, but I have no idea how to store them in an array

Comment: You use the Regex class and its Matchcollections and whatnot? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9712a7w(v=vs.110).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.copyto(v=vs.110).aspx. Did you search or try anything before posting?

Comment: and if you feel very explorative you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx and modify the printed example at the bottom to add stuff to an array (whyowhy not a list?) and not printing them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string s = "ash1a";
string pattern = @"[^h1]";
string[] matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Solved it!

Comment: @Anna Happy New Year! :)